# Opening an app from a website by using deep link

Tags: android

I want to make a share link of my android app which also has its own website. The share link will open either the app (if its installed) or will redirect to play store if app not installed. But problem is even though the app is installed in my phone, the share link still redirects to play store and not opening the app. What could be the problem. I checked the same feature in PhonePe. When we refer this app, it shows a link and on clicking it it opens app if PhonePe is already installed.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:path="/api/customer-app-redirection/Register" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: What is PhonePe?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phonepe.app
Its an app to transfer money from one user to another in India

Comment: @SomnathPal Are you sure your path is correct? Have you uploaded the .json file Android Studio might have generated for you in the correct directory? Have you tried URL Mapping in Android Studio to check if the activity is linked to the URL?

Comment: @HrishikeshKokate Sorry no. I was checking this link now https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations. Could you please tell me what is URL mapping in Android Studio here? I would like to check directly in Android Studio

Comment: @SomnatPal No what? What have you missed? The best way to implement App Links in Android Studio is to go to Tools > App Link Assistant and follow it setp-by-step.

Comment: I missed the uploading of .json file. I don't know to create it in Android Studio

Comment: Can't find App Links Assistant in Tools option